# Why there is zero article in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-article

> Does Hotbit Account Required Registration?
>
> yes, registration is required on Hotbit and registering on Hotbit is quite easy, you just
>   have to land on the homepage, and then click the “Register” button at
>   the top-right corner of home page.

I have no idea why the last two words "home page" hasn't been written without "the"?

I think It should have been written "the home page" because it has become known for the reader.

Source:
https://steemit.com/cryptocurrency/@farhan.sidiqui/hotbit-exchange-beginner-s-guide

Comment: The entire thing seems like it was written by a non-native speaker, or at the least, the text was rather poorly edited. It's a mistake; don't copy it.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in the comments:

> "The entire thing seems like it was written by a non-native speaker, or at the least, the text was rather poorly edited. It's a mistake; don't copy it." – choster